# web service is returning Axis fault ... Server.userException

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap, axis

I am having trouble with web services.

I am using one web service written in C# (usual web service, not WCF). Also, I am using one web service written in Java (Axis) for which I don't have the code (it is purchased).

That java service is calling my C# web service and expecting the return value via class SendResponse which is defined like:

```
public class SendResponse
{
    public long MessageId { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus Status { get; set; }
}

 AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in org.litesphere.www.webservices.Local.SendResponse - MessageId
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in org.litesphere.www.webservices.Local.SendResponse - MessageId
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.onStartChild(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
```

What could cause that problem?

Comment: I somehow forgot to mention that Java service is just calling my C# service and stores returned data in some database. But the Java service is storing the exception (Axis) given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was really dumb. The solution was in SendResponse class. I misspelled the MessageId property (the correct property should be MessageID) so Java couldn't parse the response.